# Safari stopped working after few hours

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, safari

After using few hours (3-4hrs approx.) safari rendering the web pages very slowly. And after few mins of that it's just stopped working. It's can't even open the google. This problem can't get resolved by restarting safari. First I suspect low memory or slow internet as the culprit, but at the same scenario other browsers like "firefox" are working smoothly. How do I get rid of this problem?

I am using MacBook Pro, OS X Yosemite (10.10.2), Safari (8.0.4)

Comment: I had also start discussion in Apple community. https://discussions.apple.com/message/27889286

Comment: googling around for you it looks like you're experiencing a common problem with safari on yosemite.  I didn't look hard but didn't see any aha! solutions for you.  Is there a more recent safari than that?

Comment: No, that's the latest one. And I am facing the same problem from few version earlier. Every time I thought it'll be solved in next version. But nothing happen at all.

Comment: Probably not a priority for apple; they'd just expect you to upgrade to Mavericks/the latest.

Comment: Yes, may be. But my macbook is just 4 month old and all the softwares are latest.

Comment: Oops yep, my bad, Yosemite comes after Mavericks.

Comment: Same problem arise after upgrading to the EI Capitan